# How to get the terminal keyboard shortcut to open the configured default terminal? (20.10 with GNOME)

Tags: gnome, 20.10, default-programs, shortcut-keys

I have configured `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` to `alacrity`. The `x-terminal-emulator` command starts `alacrity` correctly.

But the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut opens `gnome-terminal`.

How do I configure the the keyboard shortcut to open the configured terminal?

Comment: I think only way is to compile `gnome-control-center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

powerkey , settings, keyboard, shortcuts, change the existing open terminal ctrl-alt-t to something else, then set a custom shortcut below for your alacrity and set the shortcut key to ctrl-alt-t  (should work but I have not tried it)

Comment: of course you can set any other key combo , if not used already, for your alactricy.